# Unresolved errors in IntelliJ 13

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I've just setup IntelliJ 13 on my computer and set the SDK to jdk 1.7.0. I created a new project to test to see if everything is working right, but ran into a problem:

```
public class TestApp
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }
}
```

`String` and `System` gives the error "Cannot resolve symbol." Has anyone else ran into this issue or know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to go into the Project and select a valid JDK.